# Swift / PayMill: Convert PMTransaction to NSObject

Tags: ios, swift

I am using [PayMill's iOS SDK](https://github.com/paymill/paymill-ios) in a Swift project.

I can successfully create transactions, they are successfully registered with PayMill. After a transaction is created, I have the following code to pass the transaction data to my server using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire):

```
//... PayMill SDK initialization here...

PMManager.transactionWithMethod(paymentMethod, parameters: paymentParameters, consumable: true,
    success: { (transaction) -> Void in
        println("successfully created transaction: \(transaction)")
        // pass the data to my Server using Alamofire
        // Alamofire POST here...
    }, failure: { (error) -> Void in
        println("found error: \(error)")
    })
```

The Variable `transaction` is of type `PMTransaction`. [See here for more information about PMTransaction](https://github.com/paymill/paymill-ios/blob/master/macos/PayMillSDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/PMTransaction.h).

Alamofire gives the following error:

```
2015-02-05 14:56:44.434 MyApp[4070:727012] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (PMTransaction)'
```

How can I convert this to, say, a `NSObject`, or any other data type, so the data can be properly sent to my server?

I tried to declare `dataObject` with type `NSObject` before passing it to Alamofire:

```
let dataObject:NSObject = transaction as NSObject
```

But it doesn't seem to make any difference to Alamofire.

To test, I tried using a generic Object, and it was successfully stored in my database after posting it to my server through Alamofire, so the problem lies with the foreign data type `PMTransaction`.

Thanks a lot for any suggestions, I'd be very happy to post more information if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a more manual way to solve my problem. See below:

```
            var dataObject = [
                "id":"\(transaction.id)",
                "description":"\(transaction.description)",
                "amount":"\(transaction.amount)",
                "origin_amount":"\(transaction.origin_amount)",
                "currency":"\(transaction.currency)",
                "status":"\(transaction.status)",
                "livemode":"\(transaction.livemode)",
                "created_at":"\(transaction.created_at)",
                "updated_at":"\(transaction.updated_at)",
                "response_code":"\(transaction.response_code)",
            ]
```

If anyone can come up with a better way to convert `PMTransaction`, please add your solution and I will accept your answer.